# Calculate permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, permutation

I have a tuple let's say:

```
my_tuple = ((1,2), 10)
```

and a dictionary:

```
diction = {1:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 2:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 3:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)}
```

The first element of the tuple represents some variables that each of them can be assigned with a value of 1,...,9 (according to the dictionary).

How can I calculate all the permutations (without repetition) for these variables.
The only restriction I have is that I want the values of my variables to have a sum of 10.

For example:

```
(var1) = 9
(var2) = 1
```

So (9,1) has a sum of 10 and is a valid permutation.

What i have tried is:

```
lst = []

first_var = my_tuple[0][0]
sec_var = my_tuple[0][1]

for i in diction[first_var]:
    for j in diction[sec_var]:
        if i != j:
            if (i + j) == my_tuple[1]:
                lst.append((i,j))
```

My problem is that the tuple with the variables has not always the same size (2 in this case). It may has 3 or 4 variables, so the loop above wont work.

Is there any way that i can calculate the permutations for a more general case? For example, ((1,2,3), 20)?

Comment: Should it use one value from each of the dictionary values corresponding to the keys in the tuple?

Comment: Can you add a sample output for your example?

Comment: For the tuple = ((1,2,3), 20) a valid permutation would be (8,9,3). The thing is that my loop works for only 2 variables.

Comment: @prokiz Why are you checking of `i != j`? 5 + 5 is also 10, right?

Comment: I want permutations WITHOUT repetition. :]

Comment: @prokiz Okay, you still havn't answered my doubt.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get some advice shortly on how to do this in pure Python, but if the result is too slow, you should look into using a constraint solver like z3, which has clever algorithms for this kind of problem.

Comment: Can there be negative numbers in your dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use iterators:

```
def solve(d, target, total, keys, avoid):
  if total <= target:     # omit this check if values can be negative
    if keys:
      k = keys[0]
      for v in d[k]:
        if not (v in avoid):
          for s in solve(d, target, total+v, keys[1:], avoid.union([v]) ):
            yield s + [(k,v)]
    elif target == total:
      yield []

def test1():
  d = {'a':(1,2,3), 'b':(4,5), 'c':(1,3,5) }
  for s in solve(d, 10, 0, "abc", set([])):
    print s

def test2():
  d = {'a':(1,2,3), 'b':(1,2,3), 'c':(1,2,3) }
  for s in solve(d, 6, 0, "abc", set([])):
    print s
```

Output of test1:

```
[('c', 5), ('b', 4), ('a', 1)]
[('c', 3), ('b', 5), ('a', 2)]
```

Output of test2:

```
[('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 1)]
[('c', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 1)]
[('c', 3), ('b', 1), ('a', 2)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 2)]
[('c', 2), ('b', 1), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway that I can have integers as keys and not strings?

Comment: The same code works. Instead of `"abc"` just pass in a list, e.g. `[1,2,3]`.